# has there ever been an iPhone 4 without retina display

Tags: iphone

I'm not able to find information about that on the web. Has anyone out there seen such an iPhone 4? Or does anybody know for sure?

Comment: Bitte nur auf Englisch posten.

Comment: Please repost your question in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No... iPhone 4 comes with retina display.